# Story Identification - Boy invites in a female ghost who was standing under a tree outside his house

Tags: story-identification, novel, ghost

This is probably a book (or story in an anthology) from the 80s (or very early 90s).

The gist that I recall is that there's a brother and sister who see a woman standing under a tree outside their house (possibly the other side of a river), just staring at them.

I think they realise it's a ghost and eventually the boy is so fed up with seeing her that he shouts something like "Don't just stand there, come on in the house!"

That night he's woken up by a cold kiss on his forehead and sees the ghost woman standing at the foot of his bed.

The bit that I remember most about this is there were two illustrations (both black & white drawings), one of the ghost woman under the tree, and the other where she's at the bottom of the bed.  I believe she had a white shroud/dress, black hair, and huge eyes.

-edit: 2023-03-10 - removed section about asking chat gpt.  This question is being returned by Bing's new AI chat as a possible solution.  The chat gpt answer didn't provide any relevant new information.

Comment: Yeah... ChatGPT is all about creating viable-sounding but incorrect answers.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots incorrect, but if the OP finds the plot familiar it could be helpful and I appreciate the OP attributing it to ChatGPT correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate that ChatGPT isn't a dedicated knowledge base, but the plot it described seems extremely familiar (including the elements I had originally remembered) so it's possible that this story (or a synopsis of it) was part of its original training data.